# Remote Camera for Android

Tags: java, android, zigbee

Is there an open source Android application that allows you to view the image on a "spy" camera? I have a robot that has an IOIO board and a ZigBee network connection and I wanted to make it a spy robot by adding a camera. I want to view the image on this camera while the robot is driving around. It needs to be open source so I can incorporate the code that retrieves the camera pictures into my existing application that controls the robot. Please comment with the camera and open source application. Top answer might get something special :) Thanks!

Comment: Does your Android device have a ZigBee radio in it?  I wasn't aware of any Android phones/tablets that included ZigBee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zigbee doesn't really have the bandwidth to stream video.  According to the Wikipedia page: `The 2.4 GHz band provides up to 250 kbit/s, 915 MHz provides up to 40 kbit/s and 868 MHz provides a data rate up to 20 kbit/s. The actual data throughput will be less than the maximum specified bit rate due to the packet overhead and processing delays.`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee#Radio_hardware

Comment: read carefully it says >>
`**Sixteen channels** are allocated in the 2.4 GHz band`
`The raw, over-the-air data rate is 250 kbit/s **per channel** in the 2.4 GHz band`

Comment: None of the Zigbee radios I work with are able to broadcast on multiple channels simultaneously.  I guess if you had 32 Zigbee radios you could multiplex your out data across 16, and then have 16 receivers to demux the stream, giving you an effective data rate of 4000 kbit/s.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, use Zigbee. Use as a time lapse, say, once per second.

To do this camera needs a frame buffer, then you need to send that data to the receiver and then reconstruct the frame.

With Zigbee this is possible at the previous answers rates.

Only thing done I have seen is an STM development 2 board solution but it is no longer for sale.